# How to do WebDriverWait correctly with two conditions

Tags: java, selenium

I created the code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(
    new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){

        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver){

            if(driver.findElement(byLogin).isDisplayed()){

                System.out.println("test1");
                return true;
            }
            else if(driver.findElement(byConc).isEnabled()){
                System.out.println("test1");
                driver.findElement(byShop).click();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
);
```

Code after "else if" never executes. How could I make the correct ExpectedCondition having both conditions above?

Comment: A bit unclear anout what you mean. Do you want the method to return true if both the element isDisplayed AND isEnabled. or return false if both are not true?

Comment: Yes, I have two different elements, which can, but don't have to be displayed, when any of them isDisplayed and isEnabled then return true, else return false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have `return` in both `if`.`else if` blocks if need to satisfy both conditions. Instead have another `boolean` variable and return that can be overwritten from both code blocks.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(
    new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){
        boolean ind = false;

            @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver){

                if(driver.findElement(byLogin).isDisplayed()){

                    System.out.println("test1");
                    ind = true;
                }
                else if(driver.findElement(byConc).isEnabled()){
                    System.out.println("test1");
                    driver.findElement(byShop).click();
                    ind = true;
                }
                else{
                    ind = false;
                }
                return ind;
            }
        }
);
```