# WebDriverWait with multiple conditions C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

`Wait.Until` gets a selector and returns an element.

### First Question

How can you wait (poll) for multiple conditions to be met?

Problem:

```
DefaultWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(selector));
```

`Wait.Until` doesn't have an overload or a constructor with params...

### Second Question

`Wait.Until` appears to get only one condition per each poll.
Is there a way to poll over multiple conditions?

Meaning, in that same polling, check if element exists and also check if its visible  (which are two different things..)

in 1 polling sequence,

Something like the following:

```
        DefaultWait<IWebDriver> wait2 = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
        IWebElement element = wait2.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
        {
              ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(selector);
              ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(selector);
              return d.FindElement(selector);
        });
```

Comment: There's no need with your second example. `element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(selector));` already includes the `ElementExists` condition.

Comment: Maybe this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307169/how-to-do-webdriverwait-correctly-with-two-conditions. Also, good to know - http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12866/how-fluentwait-is-different-from-webdriverwait